# How can I update an array based on another array on matching index?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following two object arrays.  I would like to update array1 elements to reflect array2 elements where the transid matches.  So my result should be either a new array that has the two elements from array1 updated to reflect the values in array2, or the same array1 with the updated values.

What is the best way to do that with some of the more modern syntax?  I open to several options so I can compare.  For example, I'm guessing matching objects in array1 can just be replaced with array2 objects or the individual elements within the array1 objects can be updated through some sort of iteration over the elements.

```
var arra1 = [{
    "_id" : ObjectId("583f6e6d14c8042dd7c979e6"),
    "transid" : 1,
    "acct" : "acct1",
    "transdate" : ISODate("2012-01-31T05:00:00.000Z"),
    "category" : "category1",
    "amount" : 103 
}, {
    "_id" : ObjectId("583f6e6d14c8042dd7c2132t6"),
    "transid" : 2,
    "acct" : "acct2",
    "transdate" : ISODate("2012-01-31T05:00:00.000Z"),
    "category" : "category2",
    "amount" : 103 
}]

var arra2 = [{
    "_id" : ObjectId("583f6e6d14c8042dd7c979e6"),
    "transid" : 1,
    "acct" : "acct2",
    "transdate" : ISODate("2012-01-31T05:00:00.000Z"),
    "category" : "category5",
    "amount" : 107 
}, {
    "_id" : ObjectId("583f6e6d14c8042dd7c2132t6"),
    "transid" : 2,
    "acct" : "acct2",
    "transdate" : ISODate("2012-01-31T05:00:00.000Z"),
    "category" : "category2",
    "amount" : 103 
}, {
    "_id" : ObjectId("583f6e6d14c8042dd7c2132t6"),
    "transid" : 3,
    "acct" : "acct2",
    "transdate" : ISODate("2016-07-31T05:00:00.000Z"),
    "category" : "category3",
    "amount" : 103 
}]
```

I played with it a bit and have something like this thus far.  It's not working but that's the type of logic I'm looking for.

```
arr1.forEach(item => 
  if (arr2.indexOf(item.transid) != -1){
    item.category = arr2.indexOf(item.transid).category
  }
)
```

Comment: modern as in ES6? Meaning not worried about working on all browsers?

Comment: yes ES6. I use babel so for local development and learning purposes it's fine.  but i'm open to whatever non ES6 solution you can share for greater compatibility.

Comment: Is there a chance of having duplicate transids in either array? Meaning 0 or 1 transid per array. This will eliminate some options if array 2 might have 3 transid 1s.

Comment: No duplicates in either array.  I edited my post to add a little snippet of the logic I'm trying to set up.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
arra1 = arra1.map(item => {
  const item2 = arra2.find(i2 => i2.transid === item.transid);
  return item2 ? { ...item, ...item2 } : item;
});
```

Map all elements in `arra1` into `arra1` itself. On the mapping function try to find the correlative item in `arra2` and merge the two items with object spread if its found, if not, return the original item. Notice that spreading `item2` last is crucial to the merge, so you overwrite with the values from `item2` but keep those in `item1` that were not overwritten.

Comment: I love u hommie

Answer (score 6):

You should use the method `find` to retrieve the matching item

```
arr1.forEach(item1 => {
      var itemFromArr2 = arr2.find(item2 => item2.transid == item1.transid);

      if (itemFromArr2) {
         item1.category = itemFromArr2.category;
      }
   }
)
```

Answer (score 5):

Use reduce for this

```
let res = arr2.reduce((a,b) => {
    let a1 = arr1.find(e => e.transid === b.transid) || {};
    return a.concat(Object.assign(a1, b));
},[]);

console.log(res);
```

```js
let arr1 = [{
  "_id": ObjectId("583f6e6d14c8042dd7c979e6"),
  "transid": 1,
  "acct": "acct1",
  "transdate": ISODate("2012-01-31T05:00:00.000Z"),
  "category": "category1",
  "amount": 103
}, {
  "_id": ObjectId("583f6e6d14c8042dd7c2132t6"),
  "transid": 2,
  "acct": "acct2",
  "transdate": ISODate("2012-01-31T05:00:00.000Z"),
  "category": "category2",
  "amount": 103
}]

let arr2 = [{
  "_id": ObjectId("583f6e6d14c8042dd7c979e6"),
  "transid": 1,
  "acct": "acct2",
  "transdate": ISODate("2012-01-31T05:00:00.000Z"),
  "category": "category5",
  "amount": 107
}, {
  "_id": ObjectId("583f6e6d14c8042dd7c2132t6"),
  "transid": 2,
  "acct": "acct2",
  "transdate": ISODate("2012-01-31T05:00:00.000Z"),
  "category": "category2",
  "amount": 103
}, {
  "_id": ObjectId("583f6e6d14c8042dd7c2132t6"),
  "transid": 3,
  "acct": "acct2",
  "transdate": ISODate("2016-07-31T05:00:00.000Z"),
  "category": "category3",
  "amount": 103
}]
// MOCK
function ObjectId(i) {
  return i;
}

function ISODate(i) {
  return i;
}
//
let res = arr2.reduce((a, b) => {
  let a1 = arr1.find(e => e.transid === b.transid) || {};
  return a.concat(Object.assign(a1, b));
}, []);

console.log(res);
```