# I need to insert values into array 1 from array 2 if they match based upon two other elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know that this type of question has been asked before for I'm at a stumbling point trying to get it finished if possible and I need to ask. I have two arrays:

```
let arr1 = [{
  "Last_Name": "Smith"),
  "First_Name": "John,
  "MI": "I",
  "Fore_Name": ""),
  "Initials: ""
}, "Last_Name": "Doe"),
  "First_Name": "Mary,
  "MI": "A",
  "Fore_Name": "Mary A),
  "Initials: "MA"
},"Last_Name": "Johnson"),
  "First_Name": "Bob",
  "MI": "B",
  "Fore_Name": ""),
  "Initials: ""
}]


let arr2 = [{
  "Last_Name": "Smith"),
  "First_Name": "John,
  "MI": "I",
  "Fore_Name": "John I"),
  "Initials: "JI"
}, "Last_Name": "Doe"),
  "First_Name": "Mary,
  "MI": "A",
  "Fore_Name": "Mary A),
  "Initials: "MA"
},"Last_Name": "Johnson"),
  "First_Name": "Bob",
  "MI": "B",
  "Fore_Name": "Bob B"),
  "Initials: "BB"
}
}]
```

I want to update array1's `ForeName` and Initials fields with data from array2 IF they are blank and the `Array1["Last_Name"] = array2["Last_Name"]` AND the first character of the `Array1["First_Name"].slice(0,1) = Array2["Initials"].slice(0,1)`.
If array1's `ForeName` is not blank then skip it.

I've looked at 
[Javascript update an array based on another array on matching index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46591628/javascript-update-an-array-based-on-another-array-on-matching-index)

and I think it is close.  I understand

```
arra1 = arra1.map(item => {
  let item2 = arra2.find(i2 => i2.Last_Name === item.Last_Name);
 // not sure what to do here return item2 ? { ...item, ...item2 } : item;
});
```

And not sure how to match the first character of the First_Name with the first character of Array2 initials

Comment: please add valid data and the wanted result.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> arra1 = arra1.map(item => {
>   let item2 = arra2.find(i2 => i2.Last_Name === item.Last_Name);
>  // not sure what to do here return item2 ? { ...item, ...item2 } : item;
> });
> ```

keep track of the index while doing the map:

```
arra1 = arra1.map( (item,index) => {
// if !(item["Fore_Name"])  
// AND item["Last_Name"] === arra2[index]["Last_Name"]
// AND your slice testing (please with ===)
// THEN item["Fore_Name"] = arra2[index]["Fore_Name"]
//  item["Initials"] = arra2[index]["Initials"]
return item
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The return value of the callback of `map` is the item that will be added to the new array. So for your example the following should work. Note, you'll have to add necessary checks for undefined and null values etc.

```
arr1 = arr1.map(item => {
  // Return fast is Fore_Name already exists in arr1
  if (item.Fore_Name) return item;
  let item2 = arr2.find(i2 =>
    i2.Last_Name === item.Last_Name
    && item.First_Name.charAt(0) === i2.Initials.charAt(0));
  if (item2) {
    item.Fore_Name = item2.Fore_Name;
    item.Initials = item2.Initials;
  }
  return item;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define an objectsAreEqual function as a convenience when comparing objects from Array 1 and Array 2.

We can use this to find the relevant object from Array 2.

Note that this will result in poor performance with large arrays (since we have n squared behaviour here.) If your arrays were very large (perhaps thousands of items)  it would be better to create a map from Array2 and use this to assign values.

```js
let arr1 = [{ "Last_Name": "Smith", "First_Name": "John", "MI": "I", "Fore_Name": "", "Initials": "" }, { "Last_Name": "Doe", "First_Name": "Mary", "MI": "A", "Fore_Name": "Mary A", "Initials": "MA" }, { "Last_Name": "Johnson", "First_Name": "Bob", "MI": "B", "Fore_Name": "", "Initials": "" }]

let arr2 = [ { "Last_Name": "Smith", "First_Name": "John", "MI": "I", "Fore_Name": "John I", "Initials": "JI" }, { "Last_Name": "Doe", "First_Name": "Mary", "MI": "A", "Fore_Name": "Mary A", "Initials": "MA" }, { "Last_Name": "Johnson", "First_Name": "Bob", "MI": "B", "Fore_Name": "Bob B", "Initials": "BB" } ]; 

function objectsAreEqual(arr1Obj, arr2Obj) {
    return ((arr1Obj.Last_Name === arr2Obj.Last_Name) && (arr1Obj.First_Name.substr(0,1) === arr2Obj.Initials.substr(0,1)));
}

let result = arr1.map(arr1Obj => { 
    if (!arr1Obj.Fore_Name && !arr1Obj.Initials) {
        let arr2Match = arr2.find(arr2Obj => objectsAreEqual(arr1Obj, arr2Obj));
        if (arr2Match) {
            arr1Obj.Fore_Name = arr2Match.Fore_Name;
            arr1Obj.Initials = arr2Match.Initials;
        }
    }
    return arr1Obj;
});

console.log("Result:", result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find an element from the second array by keeping track of the index in your map function. Return the iteration item if the conditions don't match. If they match, return a modified item.

```js
const result = arr1.map((item, index) => {
  const itemTwo = arr2[index];

  if (item.Fore_Name !== "") return item;

  if (
    !(
      item.Last_Name === itemTwo.Last_Name && 
      item.First_Name[0] === itemTwo.Initials[0]
    )
  ) 
    return item;

  item.Fore_Name = itemTwo.Fore_Name;
  item.Initials = itemTwo.Initials;

  return item;
});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yhbs1ckp/).