# I am trying to retrieve result from 2 array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

i am trying to filter first array based on second array text , but i am not getting how to update the count filter to the first array from second array.

First Array:

```
var firstArray =[{text:"India",count:1,checked:true},
{text:"America",count:2,checked:false},
{text:"Uk",count:1,checked:true}];
```

Second Array:

```
var secondArray=[
{text:"India",count:1,checked:false},
{text:"America",count:1,checked:false},
{text:"Uk",count:1,checked:false}
];
```

Code:

```
var result=firstArray.filter(o1 => secondArray.some(o2 => o1.text === o2.text));
```

Result which i am currently getting:

```
var result=[
{text:"India",count:1,checked:true},
{text:"America",count:2,checked:false},
{text:"Uk",count:1,checked:true}
];
```

Result which i am trying to get is below:

```
var result=[
{text:"India",count:1,checked:true},
{text:"America",count:1,checked:false},
{text:"Uk",count:1,checked:true}
];
```

Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I update an array based on another array on matching index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46591628/how-can-i-update-an-array-based-on-another-array-on-matching-index)

Comment: It is not really clear about what is the desidered result. what is the logic of count? what is the logic of checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map the first array and pick the count from second array like this

```
var firstArray = [
  { text: "India", count: 1, checked: true },
  { text: "America", count: 2, checked: false },
  { text: "Uk", count: 1, checked: true },
];

var secondArray = [
  { text: "India", count: 1, checked: false },
  { text: "America", count: 1, checked: false },
  { text: "Uk", count: 1, checked: false },
];

firstArray
  .map((x) => {
    const tmp = secondArray.find((y) => y.text === x.text);
    return tmp ? { ...x, count: tmp.count } : null
})
  .filter(Boolean);
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would like as below

```js
var firstArray = [{
    text: "India",
    count: 1,
    checked: true
  },
  {
    text: "America",
    count: 2,
    checked: false
  },
  {
    text: "Uk",
    count: 1,
    checked: true
  }
];

var secondArray = [{
    text: "India",
    count: 1,
    checked: false
  },
  {
    text: "America",
    count: 1,
    checked: false
  },
  {
    text: "Uk",
    count: 1,
    checked: false
  }
];

var result = firstArray.map(o1 => {
  const o2 = secondArray.find(o2 => o1.text === o2.text);
  if (!o2) return;
  return { ...o1,
    count: o2.count
  }
}).filter(o1 => !!o1);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution will merge the two arrays to get the desidered result (as deduced from the answer)

```js
var firstArray =[{text:"India",count:1,checked:true},
{text:"America",count:2,checked:false},
{text:"Uk",count:1,checked:true}];

var secondArray=[
{text:"India",count:1,checked:false},
{text:"America",count:1,checked:false},
{text:"Uk",count:1,checked:false}
];

const newArray = firstArray.map((el1) => {
  let sameElList = secondArray.filter((el2) => el2.text === el1.text);
  let sameEl = sameElList.length > 0 && sameElList.pop();
  if(!sameEl){
    return el1;
  }
  el1.count = Math.min(el1.count, sameEl.count);
  el1.checked = el1.checked || sameEl.checked;
  return el1;
 });
 
 console.log(newArray);
```