# Update the value of nested object in the array based on the key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, ecmascript-6

i have two array of objects like below, am trying to compare two arrays and looking to update the object total value of arr1 if the id matches with arr2.

```
const arr1 = [
{
  id: 1,
  value: { total: 0 },
},
{
  id: 2,
  value: { total: 0 },
},
{
  id: 3,
  value: { total: 0 },
},
 id: 4,
  value: { total: 0 },
},
];

const arr2 = [
    {
      id: 2,
      value: 3 ,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      value: 5,
    },

  ];
```

I am trying to compare two arrays and looking to update the object total value of arr1 if the id matches with arr2

expected result is

```
const arr1 = [
 {
  id: 1,
 value: { total: 0 },
 },
{
id: 2,
value: { total: 3 },
},
{
 id: 3,
 value: { total: 5 },
 },
 {
  id: 4,
  value: { total: 0 },
 },
 ];
```

I have tried the below code,

```
arr1.map((item) => {
arr2.find((element) => {
  if (element.id === item.id ) {
    item = {
      ...item,
      value: {
        ...item.value,
        total: item.value.total + element.value,
      },
    };
    console.log(item);
  }
});
return item;
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I update an array based on another array on matching index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46591628/how-can-i-update-an-array-based-on-another-array-on-matching-index)

Comment: your function seems to work. u only had to reassign the output to arr1 @John_ny

Comment: its working as expected, how to reassign the output to arr1 @gil

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the find function to the filter function and will add the result to the original array.

try this

```js
const arr1 = [
{
  id: 1,
  value: { total: 0 },
},
{
  id: 2,
  value: { total: 0 },
},
{
  id: 3,
  value: { total: 0 },
},
{
  id: 4,
  value: { total: 0 },
}
]
const arr2 = [
    {
      id: 2,
      value: 3 ,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      value: 5,
    },
  ];
  
arr1.map((item) => {
  let result = arr2.filter((element) => element.id == item.id)
  if(result && result.length) {
    item.value.total += result[0].value
  }
  return item;
});  


console.log(arr1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign map to your array:

```
  this.arr1 = this.arr1.map((item) => {
      this.arr2.find((element) => {
        if (element.id === item.id) {
          item = {

            ...item,
            value: {
              ...item.value,
              total: item.value.total + element.value,
            },
          };
          console.log(item);
        }
      });
      return item;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If each object's `id` is unique (within each array), you can do:

```js
arr1.forEach((obj1) => {
  const obj2Match = arr2.find((obj2) => obj1.id === obj2.id );

  if (obj2Match) {
    obj1.value.total += obj2Match.value;
  }
});
```

If more than one object can have the same `id` (e.g. `arr2` has two objects that have the `id` of 2), then you can do:

```js
arr1.forEach((obj1) => {
  const obj2Matches = arr2.filter((obj2) => obj1.id === obj2.id );

  if (obj2Matches.length) {
    obj1.value.total += obj2Matches.reduce(((accum, curr) => accum  + curr.value), 0);
  }
});
```

Complexity:

- Time: O(N * M)
- Space: O(M)
- N => arr1.length, M => arr2.length

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this:

```
arr2.map((x) => {
  let result = arr1.filter((a1) => a1.id === x.id);
  if (result.length > 0) {
    x.total = result[0].total;
  }
  return x;
});
```